# You bought your child a stuffed bunny animal. Is it natural to say to the child: "Do you love Bunny?" or "Do you love the Bunny?"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, articles

[See this kid song](https://babyrhymes.com/kids-songs/yes-yes-playground-song/)

> ..... Bars, bars, why don‘t you climb the bars
>
> Yes, yes, yes, I want to climb the bars
>
> Good, good, the bars are fun for you
>
> Yay, yay, yay, I like them, ooh!
>
> See, see, **Monkey** likes the bars
>
> One, two, three, climbing‘s fun, you see!
>
> Yes, yes, yes, you see I‘m climbing now!
>
> Climb, climb, climb, I like it, wow! ....

---

They don't say "**the Monkey likes the bar**".

You bought your child a stuffed bunny animal. Is it natural to say to the child:

-"**Do you love Bunny?**" or "**Do you love the Bunny?**"

-"**See! Bunny likes the shoes**" or "**See! The Bunny likes the shoes**" (I say this as a way to encourage the child to wear the shoes. He sometimes doesn't listen to what I suggest to him.)

So, I guess native people may say "**Bunny**" without "**The**" when they want to refer it as a proper name or something.

When to say "**Bunny**" and when to say "**the Bunny**"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several issues are going on here.

First, this is the diction of a child. You cannot expect perfect grammar in discourse to or from a child. I have a newly born grandson; if he is speaking a language, its grammar is obscure.

Second, you are correct. If a noun becomes a proper name in a certain context, then it is treated grammatically as a name in that context. We do not say

> The Tom likes those shoes

We say

> Tom likes those shoes

If I name a dog "Monkey," I do not say to my wife

> Have you fed the monkey?

when I am asking whether the dog named "Monkey" is what is meant. I ask

> Have you fed Monkey?

In writing, you may be given an extra clue through capitalization, but of course that is irrelevant to speech.

Comment: Anyway, 'Bunny' is a nickname for a rabbit, so it's fine to call a toy or pet rabbit 'Bunny'.